# Use latest Boostrap deliverd via MAXCDN via Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, cdn

I am creating my first wordpress theme from a static site I have built which runs on Boostrap delivered by CDN.

Please no suggestions to download boostrap for this project it needs to be delivered via the CDN.

I would like to load boostrap via the CDN using my functions.php file but instead of loading it just displays the text at the top of the loaded page (there is nothing obvious in the inspector pannel and no error message it just appears to dispaly the infomration from functions.php as text).

I have included `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.php

All code from functions.php:

```
function my_scripts_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
    wp_register_script( 'gajax-js', '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'fontawsome-css', '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gajax-js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawsome-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything from the CDN, you'll have to get rid of the default jQuery expect on the backend or loginscreen.

After that you just add the CDN without ":"

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_jquery' );
function register_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin() && $GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php') {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.2');
        wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));

        wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_register_style( 'fontawsome-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js');

        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css');
        wp_enqueue_style('fontawsome-css');
    }
}
```